# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver

I am running the below code from local intellij and it works fine.I am also running the by pacaking the jars and running via java classpath which totally works fine in local.

```
    switch (browserName) {
        case "Chrome":
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            **WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();**
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("javascript.enabled");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://" + proxy);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

The same i have packaged in the jar and running in the **docker container** having base image : bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:17.0.7
i get the below error.

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:234)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
... 59 more

Selenium version : 4.8.3

My pom.xml has the following dependencies.

```
    <selenium-java>4.8.3</selenium-java>
    <webdrivermanager>5.3.2</webdrivermanager>
    <maven-assembly-plugin>3.6.0</maven-assembly-plugin>
    <testng>7.5</testng>
    <maven-resources-plugin>3.3.0</maven-resources-plugin>
    <mssql-jdbc>11.2.1.jre8</mssql-jdbc>
    <log4j-api>2.19.0</log4j-api>
    <log4j-core>2.19.0</log4j-core>
    <openxml4j>1.0-beta</openxml4j>
    <windowsazure-api>0.4.6</windowsazure-api>
    <azure-storage>3.1.0</azure-storage>
    <azure-keyvault>1.2.6</azure-keyvault>
    <adal4j>1.6.7</adal4j>
    <json-simple>1.1.1</json-simple>
    <json-path>2.7.0</json-path>
    <guava>31.0.1-jre</guava>
    <cucumber-java>7.11.2</cucumber-java>
    <cucumber-testng>7.11.2</cucumber-testng>
    <extentreports>5.0.9</extentreports>
    <assert4j>3.20.2</assert4j>
```

can anyone help resolving this ?

THe tests should run in the docker container having alpine-linux based image.
NOte : I am not using grid here.